# getActionView() of my MenuItem return null in AppCompat

Tags: android

I had this menu xml that works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/context_menu_save"
        android:actionViewClass="my.app.TextViewPlus"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        android:visible="false"/>
</menu>
```

But when i started using AppComap v7 i hade null exception when using `getActionView()`.

I change my menu layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/context_menu_save"
        myapp:actionViewClass="my.app.TextViewPlus"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        android:visible="false"/>
</menu>
```

And now it works fine. Can anyone explain, why is it happens?

Comment: [MenuItemCompat.getActionView(android.view.MenuItem)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#getActionView(android.view.MenuItem))

Comment: @Selvin but why now this attr in another package?

Comment: becuase `android:actionViewClass` was added in API 11 and before this `android:actionViewClass` is meanigless for normal API < 11 menu inflater ... Appcompat use own menu inflater which searching for `app:actionViewClass`(in other hand `app:actionViewClass` is meaningless for normal menu inflater on API >= 11 and that why you are getting null) ... do not use `menuitem.getActionView()` becuase on API < 11 you will get(i'm pretty sure) method not found exception ... use `MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuitem)`

Comment: @Selvin even with MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuitem) i get null (even on API >= 11) if using android:actionViewClass.

Comment: heh, with ABC do not use `android:actionViewClass` use `app:actionViewClass"`where app is setted like `xmlns:app ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` as i wrote menu inflater form compat library is using different xml namespace for this

Comment: @Selvin if you will write it as answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

**xmlns:myapp**  this is used when you create your own (or use others) customized views.

**xmlns:android** this is used when default android views.

so as ur question, i hope ur using your own (or use others) customized views. so u got error.

Comment: I only add support of App Compat. And after that i get null exception if using android:actionViewClass. Without App Compat usage of custom view with android:actionViewClass works fine.

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio v1.5, I see the following message for this scenario:

When using the appcompat library, menu resources should refer to the ***app:*** namespace, not the ***android:*** namespace.

When not using the appcompat library, you should be using the ***android:*** namespace.